# How to prevent authenticated users from making direct API request (Django rest framework)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

When a Django Rest Framework Site is hosted, can authenticated users make direct request to the api .. or does CORS prevent them?

Answer (score 0):

**CORS** states that every request that is not made from from the same origin will be blocked
provided that it is not in the "allowed hosts". (it concerns  requests made from other domains and can be overcome by making the request on the server-side)

**CORS** will not handle requests made individually by someone if they are from their machine directly

It depends on what you mean by

> can authenticated users make direct request to the api

You can always prevent someone from accessing something in the view

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

# But this will block them no matter wheter thy are accessing directly or not
if request.user.is_authenticated:
     return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

But in short, yes everyone can make a request to the API directly  and there is nothing wrong about it really.

**EDIT** : What you were really asking had nothing to do withs CORS but with DRM

What you want to do is use custom methods for certain types of requests e.g **GET** or **POST**

Or more specifically have users only access specific information.

Here is a very simple way to do that

- views.py (Writting your fully custom views)

```
#Mixins allow you to access only specific Methods like create,delete,list etc...
# mixins.CreateModelMixin and mixins.ListModelMixin will almost do for everything
from rest_framework import mixins, viewsets

#Take here as an example an API endpoint for creating users
class userCreation(mixins.ListModelMixin, mixins.CreateModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer #Here the serializers does not event matter you can choose something random
    queryset = User.objects.all()

    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #Here you handle user creations
        #Access POST data, validations etc
```

Or if you don't want to write everything by your self

- Serializers.py (Just limiting the fields)

```
#Here is an example where you only want to check if a username or an email exists
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username','email']
```

- views.py

```
class UserUsernameView(mixins.ListModelMixin,viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
```

Comment: I want to create an api for my React app to edit a certain model ... but the serializer contains some informations that I don’t want the user to try to edit .. by creating a PUT view .. will the user have the chase to make request to the PUT api view just by simply entering the url and sending a body

Comment: This wasn't really what the question was asking at the title, but answersed anyway (see edit), please try next time to be more precise.

Comment: thanks a whole lot... but i have already limited the fields, but i still need to create an API to edit a Model (e.g change the filed of  `has_paid=False`).. I dont want users to have the ability to request the API endpoint..  i am using **ReactJs**  as the frontend and that API endpoint will be called when the user pays a bill... how do i prevent the user from just trying to hit the API endpoint ..

Comment: if you want to **BLOCK** the request you can do something like `if not has_paid.objects.filter(user=request.user).has_paid` and return a response like `{error : "Not paid"}`, basically checking if the condition is met (inside your view) (as I said you can create your fully customizable view via `mixins`)